# How to manually match username & password for users created with Flask-User

Tags: python, hash, flask, bcrypt, flask-login

I'm implementing an api to an existing flask app, the login was created with Flask-User, however now I need to manually look up a user and match the password to authenticate.

The issue is I have no idea how to recreate the password hash to compare with the password Flask-User stored in the database.

Mostly because the Flask-User source at https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/master/flask_user/passwords.py mentions a salt however from the database columns I have :

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(user);
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|username|VARCHAR(50)|1||0
2|password|VARCHAR(255)|1|''|0
3|reset_password_token|VARCHAR(100)|1|''|0
4|email|VARCHAR(255)|1||0
5|confirmed_at|DATETIME|0||0
6|is_active|BOOLEAN|1|'0'|0
7|first_name|VARCHAR(100)|1|''|0
8|last_name|VARCHAR(100)|1|''|0
```

There is no salt. So the question is how do I generate from a plaintext password a hash that I can compare to the hashes that Flask-User created.
Here's an inconsequential sample hash;

```
$2a$12$84F1dCPN1bVYEzPswDvgZu5ma1Xk5lNepvX/X9kKFYj8Q6Dy6j95q
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this manually, rather than using the flask-user api to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the user_manager.hash_password function. https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/api.html

Comment: From the link I can even use `user_manager.verify_password(password, user)` , what would be the value of user? A username or a user object, if the latter how would I get  a user object? Thanks.

Comment: I'd assume it's the user object, but you'll have to double check. And yes I'd recommend using `verify_password` rather than writing logic yourself. Regarding security, it's better to let the framework do all the work since it's been tested and audited.